# Error in training custom data with ImageAi

Tags: python-3.x, yolo, imageai

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/imageai/Detection/Custom/gen_anchors.py in generateAnchors(train_annotation_folder, train_image_folder, train_cache_file, model_labels)
88
89         for obj in image['object']:
---> 90             relative_w = (float(obj['xmax']) - float(obj['xmin']))/image['width']
91             relatice_h = (float(obj["ymax"]) - float(obj['ymin']))/image['height']
92             annotation_dims.append(tuple(map(float, (relative_w,relatice_h))))

ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

I am getting the above error, any ideas on why it shows so?

Comment: Welcome to SO! That's probably hard to say without further information?

Comment: I am training a custom data, with imageai , however its either not recognising my files or ....... I am training it on google colab using the following: